# Update field on the Products object through field on the Contracts object

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to update the fields in Products object when the Status field in the contracts is valued "Deactivated". I am new to apex and my code doesn't seems to work. please help.

```
    trigger EndContract on Account (after update) {
    List<Contract> cont_qry = new List<Contract>();
    List<Opportunity> oppo_qry = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLine_qry = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    List<Product2> pro_qry = new List<Product2>();
    Set<ID> acc_id = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> cont_id = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> oppo_id = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> oppLine_id = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> pro_id = new Set<ID>();


for(Account acc : Trigger.new){
    acc_id.add(acc.Id);
}
cont_qry = [SELECT AccountId, Id, Status FROM Contract WHERE AccountId IN : acc_id];
for(Contract cont : cont_qry){
    cont_id.add(cont.Id);

        if (cont.Status =='Deactivated'){
           oppo_qry = [SELECT id, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :cont_Id];
           for(Opportunity oppo : oppo_qry){
           oppo_id.add(oppo.Id);
           }
           oppLine_qry = [SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN : oppo_id];
           for(OpportunityLineItem oppLine : oppLine_qry){
               oppLine_id(oppLine.Id);
           }
           pro_qry = [SELECT Available_for_lease__c,Current_Tenant__c,Id,IsActive,RecordTypeId FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN : oppLine_id];
           for(Product2 pro : pro_qry){
           pro.Available_for_lease__c = true;
           pro.Current_Tenant__c = null;
           pro.IsActive = true;
           pro.RecordTypeId = '01261000000EDF9';

           }
            }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be something like this to get you started:

```
trigger updateProduct on Contract(After Update){


    Set<ID> contractsToGet = New Set<ID>();
    Product2[] prodTBU = New Product2[]{};

    for(Contract con : conList){
        if(trigger.oldMap.get(con.id).Status != 'Deactivated' && con.Status == 'Deactivated')
            contractsToGet.add(con.id);
    }


    for(Contract con : [Select ID, (Select PriceBookEntry.Product2ID From ContractLineItems) From Contract Where Status = 'Deactivated' And ID IN :contractsToGet]){
        for(ContractLineItem li : con.ContractLineItems)
            prodTBU.add(New Product2(ID = li.PricebookEntry.Product2ID, Available_for_lease__c = true, Current_Tenant__c = null));
    }

    update prodTBU;
)
```

You will have to add in error checking and other fields to be updated etc.

Not sure why you initially had the trigger on account, why you were querying the opportunity etc as you should be able to do everything via the contract and contract line items

Comment: if ever i will be doing it in the contact object, how can i update the fields in the products object

Comment: @gelay - That is exactly what the code I have given you above will do. When contract is updated to deactivated it updates the products associated with that contract (assuming you are using ContractLineItems